# Does "Concentrations" make any sense in this context?

Tags: word-usage

Went to a job website (monster.co.uk) where you can fill out a profile, among other things asking for your education. You can enter "Degree Level", "School Name", "Dates Attended", and "Concentrations".

So the question is: Is my English much worse than I thought and "Concentrations" means anything meaningful in this context, or is this just nonsense? I assume they mean "Focus". I'd also be interested if there is better word than "Focus" as a headline for describing what your main subjects were.

Comment: What is your level of "eduction"?

Comment: Well spotted, Robusto. I fixed my typing mistake immediately. However, I can't quite see what my level of education has to with the answer to the question. Anything useful to say about that?

Comment: I think this generally refers to if you have a degree in a broad field but there is a specific application or area within the field you concentrated or as you say 'focused' on. For example if I had a degree in Archaeology I may have a concentration in Meso-American archaeology.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, to my great surprise, that actually "Concentrations" does make sense in the context. I have never heard the word used in this way, but according to Merriam-Webster one of the meanings of concentration is

> 1 a :  the act or process of concentrating :  the state of being >concentrated; especially :  direction of attention to a single object
>
> b :  an academic major or area of focus within a major

So while I'm not sure how this reflects on your knowledge of English there certainly is a reasonable way to interpret Concentrations in the context given. And I learned a new meaning today.:)

Comment: I'm surprised as well!

Comment: I'm surprised you're surprised, as in American English *concentration* in this context is generally understood as your area of study, although a far less common term than *major*, and usually indicating a specialization within the discipline. I was a *history major with a concentration in classical civilization*. And some institutions do not use the term *major* and *minor*; Harvard uses *concentration* and *secondary* for example.

Comment: Well, I don't speak American English. So it seems quite inappropriate on a UK web site.